# I get this error when building my Transport app

Tags: flutter, dart

Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 421
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 41s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            164.9s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1